# error TS2531 Object is possibly 'null' in angular reactive forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I try angular reactive form validation and template driven form validation,but reactive form validation show me an error like that ,null when I try to compile and run. My angular version is 10.0.14

So, I have the component.html

```
<form action=""
  [formGroup]="singupForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Username</label>
      <input
      type="text"
      id="userName"
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="userName"
      >
      <span
      *ngIf="username.invalid"
      class="help-block"
      >Please enter valid username!</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

following is the component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

     @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
     })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    singupForm! : FormGroup;
    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){
     this.singupForm = new FormGroup({
     userName : new  FormControl(null, Validators.required)
     });
     }
       get username(){
        return this.singupForm.get('userName');
         }

         onSubmit(){
          console.log(this.singupForm.value)
         }
```

}
app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
],

imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule
],

   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Error is just like that

```
   ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:16:27 - error TS2531: Object is 
   possibly 'null'.

   16           *ngIf="username.invalid"
                         ~~~~~~~ src/app/app.component.ts:6:16
   6   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

   ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open 
     your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Comment: Can you post more of the error and where it occurred?

Comment: Which line is showing the error?

Comment: post error code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530435/2131286) is correct in a sense that the error goes away and your application can compile, it does not address the problem, nor explains why it happens.

The core of the issue is, as the error message you've posted suggests, that the `username` property on the class could be `null`. This is how you define it:

```
get username () {
  return this.singupForm.get('userName')
}
```

Indeed, if you take a look at [the implementation of `FormGroup#get` in Angular's source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2e7eb270dfe26d157b8bf819fcb669d9f0d0a066/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L845-L847), you'll see that the return type is `AbstractControl | null` just form the signature:

```
get (path: Array<string|number>|string): AbstractControl | null
```

So even though *you* know that in *your case* `form.get('userName')` will surely return an instance of `FormControl`, Angular cannot be sure that you didn't remove it in the meantime, or change its type to something else like `FormArray` or `FormGroup` or your own custom class extending `AbstractControl`. The best Angular can do is tell you that's either some sort of `AbstractControl`, or that it's maybe `null` if you'd removed it in the meantime.

From the code your posted, it doesn't look like you're changing or removing `userName` in the `signupForm`, so a better solution is probably to do and explicit cast:

```
get username () {
  return this.singupForm.get('userName') as FormControl
}
```

This tells TypeScript:

> Look, I know what I'm doing. Yes, `get` could return `null`, but *I* know that it won't, for *my case*. So please treat this value as if its type were `FormControl`.

Now, in your template (and everywhere else), you can simply use `{{ username.valid }}`, as you originally intended.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got this error, you can use '?' to solve this problem
see the following code. Eg;

```
 *ngIf="username?.invalid"
```